# Access to the path denied [Windows 10]

Tags: xml, windows-10, edit, access-denied

Doing below action in C# windows application for decrypting and editing xml file, but always get "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\...\Demo.xml' is denied." at save file in Windows 10.

```
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                string xml_path = Utility.Decrypt_xml_files();
                xmldoc.Load(xml_path);

                //XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("Programs/Code")[glbCard - 1];
                XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Code")[glbCard - 1];
                xmlnode.SelectSingleNode("Revision").InnerText = txtRevision.Text;

                // save
                xmldoc.Save(xml_path);
```

Comment: Because by default a program running without administrative access can't write to Program Files folder...

Comment: Running Microsoft Visual Studio as administrator with full control. Also other *.ini files updating successfully.

Comment: Do you also have write privileges to _that_ file? Is the file marked as read-only?

Comment: Yes...full control given to file and folder both.

Comment: Read-only? Can you edit it with, let's say, Notepad?

Comment: You might need to check what's going inside "Utility.Decrypt_xml_files();" this may be locking the file.

Comment: Yes, I can...I m decryption lots of ini file with same function...all doing well...only failure occurs in case of xml file.

Comment: Stack error : at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)